# Simple way to fill in all the cells in a column with the same string

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, match, array-formulas

Newby here. I would like a simple way, if it exists, to fill in a column with the same string/number.

The formula should not specify the number of rows (or the last row to fill in) but should propagate the string/number to the last cell of the column.

At the moment I'm using this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Hello"}&$B:$B)
```

that writes my string ("Hello" in this case) concatenated with the content of its right cell. So this work (write just "Hello" in all the column cell) *if* the column B is empty :)

Can I simplify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(ROW(A:A)/0; "Hello"))
```

or just:

```
=INDEX(IF(ROW(A:A); "hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array formula with `IF()`. Try-

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A<>"","Hello"&A:A,""))
```

Or `BYROW()` in this way.

```
=BYROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),LAMBDA(x,"Hello"&x))
```

Comment: Thanks @Harun24hr ! They are a bit complicated for my taste but maybe it's possible to improve them.... I have been able to simplify the first one a little bit.

`=ArrayFormula(IF(Z:Z,"Hello","Hello"))`

To avoid to specify "Hello" twice I also tried this but it doesn't work:

=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(1,Z:Z),"Hello"))

Comment: It would be `=ArrayFormula(IF(Z:Z,"Hello",""))`

Comment: No, `=ArrayFormula(IF(Z:Z,"Hello",""))` works only if Z column is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other ways:

```
=makearray(rows(A:A),1,lambda(r,c,"Hello"))

=scan("Hello",sequence(rows(A:A)),lambda(a,c,a))

=query(query(sequence(rows(A:A)),"select 'Hello'"),"offset 1")
```